# Send me email if IP address is in access log more than 1000 times

Tags: linux, bash

I have a cron that runs every 10 minutes, the cronjob name is access.log.

It extract IP addresses from my apache log, count them, and sort them.

```
cat access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

However, I want this cron to send me email when a particular ip hit or browse my website for more than 1000 times. However, if the count is less than 1000 times then it should not send me an email.

Comment: Why asking again?  Yesterday you asked the same http://stackoverflow.com/q/28969547/ and got an answer. Give feedback to that one and eventually accept it

Comment: HI Fedorqui, I did add a comment to the question which i asked yesterday, you can check it to see my comment.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, I already had seen it. The issue is that if you don't get the desired answer you cannot post the same question. Instead, edit the original one, provide more relevant details and, of course, indicate what is failing to the answerers who invested some time on it.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of Cron is to send you email if the script generates output.  Make it not generate any output if your condition isn't met.

```
awk '{print $1}' access.log |
sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr |
awk '$1 >= 1000'
```

(This also fixes the [useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).)